# Does Google App Engine's Java8 runtime support Stream API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8

I have a project that use AppEngine 1.9.54 on server and GWT 2.8 on client. When I use the Stream API on server side it always threw this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.stream.Collectors is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

The code that use Stream API on client is ok, just the server side code. Does GAE java8 runtime support Stream API?

Comment: well according to this they should support it since June this year : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35895687

Comment: alos see this https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html